# KIVY value error

Tags: python-2.7, kivy-language

Trying to go over the weather app creating int he book Creating Apps with Kivy. I am currently having an error that I do not know how to resolve.

I get the following `error`:

> city, country = data_item
>    ValueError: too many values to unpack

Any help appreciated to solve this error

Python Code:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import json

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.factory import Factory   

class LocationButton(ListItemButton):
    location = ListProperty()    

class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):
    search_results = ObjectProperty()
    search_input = ObjectProperty()

    def args_converter(self, index, data_item):    
        city, country = data_item    
        return {'location':(city, country)}   

    def search_location(self):
        search_template = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q={}&type=like&APPID=" + "a3ce4c4c978cae4ace6c3e404899ac32"

        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location)

        #TODO : Error Checking if location is not found

    def found_location(self, request, data):
        data = json.loads(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data    

        cities = ["{}({})".format(d['name'], d['sys']
                                  ['country']) for d in data['list']]   

        self.search_results.item_strings = cities
        del self.search_results.adapter.data[:]
        self.search_results.adapter.data.extend(cities)
        self.search_results._trigger_reset_populate()   

        #TODO: Error checking if network failure

class WeatherRoot(BoxLayout):
    current_weather = ObjectProperty()

    def show_current_weather(self, location):

        self.clear_widgets()

        if location is None and self.current_weather is None:
            location = ("New York (US)", "US")

        if location is not None:
            self.current_weather = Factory.CurrentWeather()
            self.current_weather.location = location

        self.add_widget(self.current_weather)

    def show_add_location_form(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(AddLocationForm())

class WeatherApp(App):
    pass    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

Kivy File:

```
#: import main weather
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter

WeatherRoot:

<WeatherRoot>:    
    AddLocationForm:

<AddLocationForm>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    search_input: search_box
    search_results: search_results_list

    BoxLayout:
        height: '40dp'
        size_hint_y: None

        TextInput:
            id: search_box
            size_hint_x: 50
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.search_location()

        Button:
            text: 'Search'
            size_hint_x: 25   

            on_press: root.search_location()
        Button:
            text: 'Current Location'
            size_hint_x: 25

    ListView:
        id: search_results_list
        adapter:
            ListAdapter (data = [], cls= main.LocationButton,
            args_converter = root.args_converter)
    Button:
        text: 'Cancel'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '40dp'
        on_press: app.root.show_current_weather(None)

<LocationButton>:
    text: "{} ({})".format(self.location[0], self.location[1])
    height: "40dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    on_press: app.root.show_current_weather(self.location)

<CurrentWeather@BoxLayout>:
    location: ['New York', 'US']
    conditions: None
    temp: None
    temp_min: None
    temp_max: None
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: "{} ({})".format(root.location [0], root.location[1])
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '40dp'
        Button:
            text: 'Add Location'
            on_press: app.root.show_add_location_form()
        Button:
            text: "Forecast"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out myself. I was passing a string to the args_converter; but I needed to pass a tuple. THis code below will fix the above code.

```
cities = [(d['name'], d['sys']['country']) for d in data['list']]
```